# Oppo A1601 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, oppo

The problem does not happen on other phones or emulator.

The app runs fine if I install and launch app separately using command line:
`./gradlew clean installMyApp && adb shell "am start -n com.abc.xyz/com.abc.xyz.activities.landing.splash.SplashScreen`

Within the same day, the class name seems to be consistent. However, when I tried again a few days apart, it's a different class "missing"

Stacktrace as of today 30th Oct 2017:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.abc.xyz, PID: 24924
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler
                      at rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.from(AndroidSchedulers.java:63)
                      at com.abc.xyz.di.app.AppModule.provideLooperScheduler(AppModule.java:77)
                      at com.abc.xyz.di.app.AppModule_ProvideLooperSchedulerFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideLooperSchedulerFactory.java:15)
                      at com.abc.xyz.driver.di.app.AppModule_ProvideLooperSchedulerFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideLooperSchedulerFactory.java:8)
                      at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
                      at com.abc.xyz.AppLogicComponent_Factory.get(AppLogicComponent_Factory.java:110)
                      at com.abc.xyz.AppLogicComponent_Factory.get(AppLogicComponent_Factory.java:23)
                      at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
                      at com.abc.xyz.MyApplication_MembersInjector.injectMembers(MyApplication_MembersInjector.java:167)
                      at com.abc.xyz.MyApplication_MembersInjector.injectMembers(MyApplication_MembersInjector.java:23)
                      at com.abc.xyz.di.app.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:2865)
                      at com.abc.xyz.di.app.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:842)
                      at dagger.android.DaggerApplication.injectIfNecessary(DaggerApplication.java:78)
                      at dagger.android.DaggerApplication.onCreate(DaggerApplication.java:53)
                      at com.abc.xyz.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:81)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4996)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:188)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

Note that I see **many different and unrelated classes** "missing" from time to time. This is only one example and should not have anything to do with the problem itself:
(dependency injection with Dagger 2)

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@Module(includes = NetModule.class)
class AppModule {

    //...

    @AppComponent.AppScope
    @Provides
    static Scheduler provideLooperScheduler() {
        // Please be sure not to execute long run executions with this scheduler
        // This scheduler is meant to be beneficial in timer/interval/retry/timeout/sample/window these rx.Operators
        final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("RxLooperHandler");
        handlerThread.start();
        return AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    //...    
}
```

Comment: Paste your code

Comment: I've seen the same exact issue with different classes which are not related to each other in any way. So, what code to include? @SushinPv

Comment: Try a Build > Clean Project and then run again.

Comment: I've done that many times, I've never posted on StackOverflow without trying clean + rebuild first the many years I've been here. Please take a way your downvote @SushinPv

Comment: have tried multi-dex?

Comment: Just try to clean Project and then gradle sync

Comment: How is multi-dex the solution for anything here? It's merely a necessity for large apps like mine (we've been using it for years without problem) @OmInfowaveDevelopers